# Jenkins Delete build if not promoted

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using promoted build plugin. When jobA is promoted, jobB is triggered. 
I want to get rid of delayed approval.

So, my requirement is to delete jobA's latest build or all the builds automatically after certain triggered time if jobA is not promoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do it juste  with promoted build plugîn but you can use an other job who receive  the job url and build id in parameters to execute a http request or curl request using the jenkins cli to delete the specific build

Comment: ok. But what about the time limit to wait ? I mean I want it to wait for let say 1 day and then delete the build

Comment: this job can have a cron configuration to start it every day at midnight for example

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I am new to http request plugin. Can you help me with the input to delete a build from another job? Thanks in advacne

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/589528/how-do-i-delete-the-builds-11-to-1717-in-jenkins